# Passing Information from one view Controller to another

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, segue

This my main veiw controller code where I populate table veiw with JSON data which I decoded and i have prepare for segue function that i need help with. I want to know to pass title of the movie and overview to next view controller:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  var name = [String]()
    var dis = [String]()
      let urls = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=964086a2711d5d6f3fa828013fd5c3b0&language=en-US&page=1"



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
         tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Mov", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "hello")
        session()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }



    func session(){
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: .main)
        let url = URL(string: urls)!
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil){
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            if let safeData = data{
                self.parseJSON(movieData:safeData)
            }
        })
        task.resume()

    }



          func parseJSON (movieData :Data){
                      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                      do{
                      let decodeData = try decoder.decode(MovieData.self, from: movieData)
                          for movie in decodeData.results {
                              self.name.append(movie.title)
                           self.dis.append(movie.overview)
                           self.tableView.reloadData()
                       //print(movie.overview)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                          }
                          // print("\(self.name)")
                       //print(self.name.count)



                      }catch{
                          print(error)
                      }



                  }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let des = segue.destination as! DetViewController

    }

}


extension FirstViewController:UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //print(name.count)
        return name.count
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hello", for: indexPath) as! Mov
        cell.topLabel.text = self.name[indexPath.row]
        cell.bottomLabel.text=self.dis[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

extension FirstViewController:UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "dhruv", sender: self)
    }
}
```

This code below is the struct that i am using to decode my JSON data :

```
import UIKit
struct MovieData:Decodable {
    var results : [Result]
}
struct Result:Decodable {
    var title : String
    var overview:String
}
```

And lastly I have my destination veiw controller which were I am tryong to pass my information too such as movie title and overview;

```
import UIKit

class DetViewController: UIViewController {

    var movie : MovieData
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
print(movie)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




}
```

So if would help i would appreciate it. The main purpiose for this is that at end if someone click on the cell with name of the movie i want to display the name and overveiw of the movie in to the screen . I am able to get to new view Controller when i press on one of the cell in the table view i just figure how to pass the value.

Comment: https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to declare a variable of type MovieData to hold your decoded data. Let's call it movieData and make sure you declare it at the top of your ViewController:

   `var movieData: MovieData?`
2. Inside of your parseJSON() function, you want to assign the decoded data to your movieData variable.

   `movieData = decodeData`
3. According to your code and your question, I'm pretty sure you are trying to pass the info about the movie selected and not the whole results array. So, if that's the case, inside DetViewController, change the type of movie to Result, since you are only interested in a specific movie.

   `var movie: Result`

In prepareForSegue, assign the value of the selected movie to your DetViewController's movie property (and that's how you pass data to your next ViewController):

```
 if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
     des.movie = movieData.results[indexPath.row]
 }
```

Now inside your DetViewController, you can access title and overview as follows: movie.title and movie.overview

A piece of advice:
Instead of naming your structs MovieData and Result, consider naming them MovieArray and Movie. Instead of naming your MovieData property results, consider naming it movies.